# Excel - Running IF/ELSE logic on user selection

Tags: excel, vba

I want the run an IF/ELSE statement across the range of cells selected by the user.
Currently which ever IF/ELSE statement is true for the first cell in the selection, is then applying to all the cells in the section rather than doing a for each loop.

```
Sub MultiCellTest()
  With Selection
    If ActiveCell > 10 Then
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 6684927
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Else
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 16764159
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: `For Each cell in Selection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would modify your code to handle each cell in the active selection.

```
Sub MultiCellTest()
  For Each cell in Selection
    If cell > 10 Then
        With cell.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 6684927
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Else
        With cell.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 16764159
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that! That is working perfectly. :)

Comment: Just realized it does not work with declaring cell as excel ready knows that variable. After removing that line it works fine.